# AnkhSVN Visual Studio - SSRS Project File "You are trying to commit conflicted items"

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I am receiving the following error message:

> You are trying to commit conflicted items.  Please review the
>   conflicted files and resolve them, or remove the check when retrying
>   the commit.

I went through the `Edit Conflicts screen` and chose the copy to keep, selected "Resolve Conflict", on the visual studio prompt I chose "Reload All Files".  I tried to commit the files after resolving the conflict, but I get the same message.

Can someone help?  Why will it not keep the copy that I have selected?

---

**ANKHSVN-EditConflicts (step1-2) (Edit Conflicts).png**
[image]

**ANKHSVN-EditConflicts (step3) (Choose the keep copy).png**
[image]

**ANKHSVN-EditConflicts (step4-5) (AcceptMerge-ReloadAll).png**
[image]

**ANKHSVN-EditConflicts (step6-7) (Commit) (cyclical error message).png**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER:

In "Step 2" instead of `Edit Conflict` I had to choose the option `Resolve> Resolve Conflict`.

I was then able to commit the changes.